# Why MYVAR=something wont appear in printenv? Is this related to getenv function?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, c

Im trying to understand why [getenv from stlib.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) returns non null for `PATH` but not for my custom defined variables like `ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT`. I think it has something to do with this:

```
ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=test
printenv | grep ANDR
#nothing
```

Why my defined variables wont appear in `printenv`? Is this related to why `getenv("ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT")==NULL` even though the variable is defined in the same shell that executes the binary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By writing

```
ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=test
```

you only set the shell variable `ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT` in the current shell. If you want to make it an environment variable, available to forked processes (i.e., to any command you execute from that shell), you need to export the variable:

```
export ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT
```

You can also set the variable and mark it for automatic export in one line:

```
export ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=test
printenv | grep ANDR # outputs: ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=test
```

If you do not want to automatically export the variable for all forked programs, but only make it available to a specific program (say, `./myprogram`) you want to execute, you can do that like so:

```
ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=test ./myprogram
```